# How to test logic trees - 1 unexpected test outcome out of 10

Tags: c#, if-statement

> I have submitted a program to satisfy a Business Requirement statement, but the feedback that I get back says that 1 out of 10 inputs is wrong. I am not sure which inputs are wrong or how to identify them.

Pepi calls you and asks you to write a program that prints a specific result on the console. After several soccer matches, he noticed that between certain minutes a player always misses a penalty, receives a yellow card, scores a goal, receives a free-kick or misses a corner.

Sign in

The console reads 2 lines:

- First row - minutes - integer positive in the interval [0… 10000]
- Second line - player name - text

Exit

In the first line, print:

- "Match has just started!" - if the minutes are 0.
- "First half time." - if the minutes are less than 45.
- "Second half time." - if the minutes are 45 or more.

In the following line print:

- If the minutes are between 1 and 10 inclusive:
  "{player name} missed a penalty."

  - If at the same time the minutes are an even number, print:
  - "{player name} was injured after the penalty."
- If the minutes are greater than 10 and less than or equal to 35:
  "{player name} received a yellow card."

  - If at the same time the minutes are an odd number, print:
  - "{player name} got another yellow card."
- If the minutes are greater than 35 and less than 45:
  "{Player Name} SCORED A GOAL !!!"
- If the minutes are greater than 45 and less than or equal to 55.
  "{player name} got a freekick."

  - If at the same time the minutes are an even number, print:
  - "{player name} missed the freekick."
- If the minutes are greater than 55 and less than or equal to 80.
  "{player name} missed a shot from the corner."

  - If at the same time the minutes are an odd number,
  - "{player name} has been changed with another player."
- If the minutes are greater than 80 and less than or equal to 90: "{Player Name} SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!!"

Example input and output

```
Login Exit Explanation
85
Harry Kane Second half time.
Harry Kane SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! The minutes are over 45 and we print the first line, then we see that they are in the range of 80 to 90 and we print the second line.
10
Messi First half time.
Messi missed a penalty.
Messi was injured after the sentence.
25
Ronaldo First half time.
Ronaldo received a yellow card.
Ronaldo got another yellow card.
```

> The following is my program, but 1 test input out of 10 gave out a wrong answer. I don't know the input itself, but if you helped, it would mean a lot.

```
          string name;
          minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
          name = Console.ReadLine();
              if (minutes == 0) Console.WriteLine("Match has just began!");
              else if (minutes < 45) Console.WriteLine("First half time.");
              else Console.WriteLine("Second half time.");
              if (minutes == 0) placeholder = 0;
              else if (minutes > 0 && minutes <= 10) { Console.WriteLine(name + " missed a penalty."); if (minutes % 2 == 0) Console.WriteLine(name + " was injured after the penalty."); }
              else if (minutes <= 35) { Console.WriteLine(name + " received yellow card."); if (minutes % 2 != 0) Console.WriteLine(name + " got another yellow card."); }
              else if (minutes <= 45) Console.WriteLine(name + " SCORED A GOAL !!!");
              else if (minutes <= 55) { Console.WriteLine(name + " got a freekick."); if (minutes % 2 == 0) Console.WriteLine(name + " missed the freekick."); }
              else if (minutes <= 80) { Console.WriteLine(name + " missed a shot from corner."); if (minutes % 2 != 0) Console.WriteLine(name + " has been changed with another player."); }
              else if (minutes <= 90) Console.WriteLine(name + " SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!!");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Can you format the question text and code as well as reduce to the minimum necessary, please? It is unreadable and requires a lot of work that you must do yourself, please.

Comment: What is he "wrong" output? How do you know it's wrong if you don't know the input?

Answer (score 0):

> Welcome to SO! Rather than posting exact questions from homework, tutorials or assignments you should focus on the [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that highlights the specific issue that you would like resolved. A single source question in the real world may result in multiple isolated questions posted on SO, the process of isolating your example often leads to greater understanding and the solution by itself.
>
> > Your remark that you know that "*1 test input out of 10 gave out a wrong answer*" but the fact that you don't know which one, highlights that you have not tried to run this code yourself for combinations outside of the example text.

Initially, it is not clear what your issue is, which is why this question has been down voted so much, so I'm going to help you solve this problem by sharing my thoughts along the way.

When I run your code, the output almost matches the example, I think your example has some mistakes though, so this output looks correct:

```
85
Harry Kane
Second half time.
Harry Kane SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!!
10
Messi
First half time.
Messi missed a penalty.
Messi was injured after the penalty.
25
Ronaldo
First half time.
Ronaldo received yellow card.
Ronaldo got another yellow card.
```

But now you need to get creative and follow through each of the criteria specified in the question and prove that you can get the correct output.

You have already demonstrated that you know how to capture a name from the input and use it in the console output, and you have also demonstrated isolation in your `if` branches so the only issue you have really is how to come up with a good way to test the other branches in your logic.

For logic scenarios like this I always try to formulate a test harness, or unit tests that cover off all of the boundary conditions. It can be a tedious process but with *greater than, less than* and *equals* comparisons its the only way to be 100% sure that your logic is correct.

> *Unit Testing* and *Test Harnesses* are techniques you can use to automate testing, it is code or an app that runs your code and provides specific inputs and compares the outputs from your code against the expected output.

Lets build a Matrix of the expected outputs but for simplicity lets focus on the time input only. (as mentioned above you have the name injection covered)
So identify all the boundary conditions for time, including the minimum and maximum values, and write out the expected outputs.

> The boundary to test is the number printed in the business requirement, to test it adequately you need to test either side of that number to ensure that you have the correct equality statement:
>
> > *"If the minutes are between 1 and 10 inclusive"*
> >     This requirement has two boundaries, `1` and `10`, the `inclusive` operator tells us that the possible range includes the boundary values, either way, we should test the following values to confirm we have the correct boundary conditions: 0,1,2,9,10,11
>
> It is pretty common in programming to be accidentally off by 1 so this form of testing will pickup those issues.

We will also split the testing into three results matrices, one for the first line as its result conditions are mutually exclusive from the remaining lines, one for the second line as it is a clear logic branch that also produces results that are exclusive from the other conditions, the last matrix covers the third line output. These could be all combined into a single matrix but that makes it harder to identify which code branch is incorrect.

**First Line Output Test Cases**

```
| Time | Expected First Line     | First Line Output     | Result |  
|------|-------------------------|-----------------------|--------|  
|    0 | Match has just started! |                       |        |  
|    1 | First half time.        |                       |        |  
|   44 | First half time.        |                       |        |  
|   45 | Second half time.       |                       |        |    
|   46 | Second half time.       |                       |        |  
|10000 | Second half time.       |                       |        |
```

**Second Line Output Test Cases**

> Player Name for these tests will be `"Px"` this keeps the output small enough to display in this forum.

```
| Time | Expected Second Line              | Second Line Output    | Result |  
|------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------|--------|  
|    0 |                                   |                       |        |  
|    1 | Px missed a penalty.              |                       |        |
|    9 | Px missed a penalty.              |                       |        |  
|   10 | Px missed a penalty.              |                       |        |  
|   11 | Px received a yellow card.        |                       |        |    
|   34 | Px received a yellow card.        |                       |        |  
|   35 | Px received a yellow card.        |                       |        |
|   36 | Px SCORED A GOAL !!!              |                       |        |
|   44 | Px SCORED A GOAL !!!              |                       |        |
|   45 |                                   |                       |        |
|   46 | Px got a freekick.                |                       |        |
|   54 | Px got a freekick.                |                       |        |
|   55 | Px got a freekick.                |                       |        |
|   56 | Px missed a shot from the corner. |                       |        |
|   79 | Px missed a shot from the corner. |                       |        |
|   80 | Px missed a shot from the corner. |                       |        |
|   81 | Px SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! |                       |        |
|   89 | Px SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! |                       |        |
|   90 | Px SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! |                       |        |
|   91 |                                   |                       |        | 
|10000 |                                   |                       |        |
```

As long as the above test conditions pass, we can skip the known boundary testing for the second line statements and just test for the boundaries that affect the third line. However as the third line conditions affect ever second value (mapped to Odd or Even numbers), use the boundary and go one whole sequence inside the range, to be thorough or if you are automating the test cases, you should test all possible values within the range. Here if the range was large enough I put some random test cases in.

```
| Time | Expected Third Line                      | Second Line Output    | Result |  
|------|------------------------------------------|-----------------------|--------|  
|    1 |                                          |                       |        |
|    2 | Px was injured after the penalty.        |                       |        |
|    3 |                                          |                       |        |
|    8 | Px was injured after the penalty.        |                       |        |
|    9 |                                          |                       |        |  
|   10 | Px was injured after the penalty.        |                       |        |  
|   11 | Px got another yellow card.              |                       |        |    
|   12 |                                          |                       |        |    
|   13 | Px got another yellow card.              |                       |        |    
|   22 |                                          |                       |        |    
|   27 | Px got another yellow card.              |                       |        |    
|   33 | Px got another yellow card.              |                       |        |    
|   34 |                                          |                       |        |  
|   35 | Px got another yellow card.              |                       |        |
|   36 |                                          |                       |        |
|   44 |                                          |                       |        |
|   45 |                                          |                       |        |
|   46 | Px missed the freekick.                  |                       |        |
|   47 |                                          |                       |        |
|   50 | Px missed the freekick.                  |                       |        |
|   53 |                                          |                       |        |
|   54 | Px missed the freekick.                  |                       |        |
|   55 |                                          |                       |        |
|   56 |                                          |                       |        |
|   57 | Px has been changed with another player. |                       |        |
|   58 |                                          |                       |        |
|   62 |                                          |                       |        |
|   65 | Px has been changed with another player. |                       |        |
|   74 |                                          |                       |        |
|   79 | Px has been changed with another player. |                       |        |
|   80 |                                          |                       |        |
|   81 |                                          |                       |        |
|10000 |                                          |                       |        |
```

This is my evaluation of these test matricies, I provided this in two steps to demonstrate the process, you identify the expected results first, from the business requirements, even before you write any code. Knowing all the facts up front will help you identify the branching logic before you start to write any code.

**First Line Output Test Result**

> Only the specific text value differs from the Business Requirement when Time = zero

```
| Time | Expected First Line     | First Line Output     | Result |
|------|-------------------------|-----------------------|--------|
|    0 | Match has just started! | Match has just began! |  FAIL  |  
|    1 | First half time.        | First half time.      |  Pass  |  
|   44 | First half time.        | First half time.      |  Pass  |  
|   45 | Second half time.       | Second half time.     |  Pass  |   
|   46 | Second half time.       | Second half time.     |  Pass  |
|10000 | Second half time.       | Second half time.     |  Pass  |
```

**Second Line Output Test Cases**

> Notice again spelling mistakes in the output, *"received yellow card"* instead of *"received **a** yellow card"* and *"missed a shot from corner"* instead of *"missed a shot from **the** corner"*

You also need to consider the boundary conditions from this Business requirement:

> - If the minutes are greater than 35 and less than 45: "{Player Name} SCORED A GOAL !!!"
> - If the minutes are greater than 45 and less than or equal to 55. "{player name} got a freekick."

Notice there is no condition that matches 45 exactly

```
| Time | Expected Second Line              | Second Line Output                | Result |
|------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|--------|
|    0 |                                   |                                   |  Pass  |
|    1 | Px missed a penalty.              | Px missed a penalty.              |  Pass  |
|    9 | Px missed a penalty.              | Px missed a penalty.              |  Pass  |
|   10 | Px missed a penalty.              | Px missed a penalty.              |  Pass  |
|   11 | Px received a yellow card.        | Px received yellow card.          |  FAIL  |
|   34 | Px received a yellow card.        | Px received yellow card.          |  FAIL  |
|   35 | Px received a yellow card.        | Px received yellow card.          |  FAIL  |
|   36 | Px SCORED A GOAL !!!              | Px SCORED A GOAL !!!              |  Pass  |
|   44 | Px SCORED A GOAL !!!              | Px SCORED A GOAL !!!              |  Pass  |
|   45 |                                   | Px SCORED A GOAL !!!              |  FAIL  |
|   46 | Px got a freekick.                | Px got a freekick.                |  Pass  |
|   54 | Px got a freekick.                | Px got a freekick.                |  Pass  |
|   55 | Px got a freekick.                | Px got a freekick.                |  Pass  |
|   56 | Px missed a shot from the corner. | Px missed a shot from corner.     |  FAIL  |
|   79 | Px missed a shot from the corner. | Px missed a shot from corner.     |  FAIL  |
|   80 | Px missed a shot from the corner. | Px missed a shot from corner.     |  FAIL  |
|   81 | Px SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! | Px SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! |  Pass  |
|   89 | Px SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! | Px SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! |  Pass  |
|   90 | Px SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! | Px SCORED A GOAL FROM PENALTY !!! |  Pass  |
|   91 |                                   |                                   |  Pass  |
|10000 |                                   |                                   |  Pass  |
```

**Third Line Output Test Cases**

> These conditions all pass, here is the result of the matrix anyway

```
| Time | Expected Third Line                      | Third Line Output                        | Result |
|------|------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------|--------|
|    1 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|    2 | Px was injured after the penalty.        | Px was injured after the penalty.        |  Pass  |
|    3 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|    8 | Px was injured after the penalty.        | Px was injured after the penalty.        |  Pass  |
|    9 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   10 | Px was injured after the penalty.        | Px was injured after the penalty.        |  Pass  |
|   11 | Px got another yellow card.              | Px got another yellow card.              |  Pass  |
|   12 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   13 | Px got another yellow card.              | Px got another yellow card.              |  Pass  |
|   22 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   27 | Px got another yellow card.              | Px got another yellow card.              |  Pass  |
|   33 | Px got another yellow card.              | Px got another yellow card.              |  Pass  |
|   34 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   35 | Px got another yellow card.              | Px got another yellow card.              |  Pass  |
|   36 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   44 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   45 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   46 | Px missed the freekick.                  | Px missed the freekick.                  |  Pass  |
|   47 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   50 | Px missed the freekick.                  | Px missed the freekick.                  |  Pass  |
|   53 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   54 | Px missed the freekick.                  | Px missed the freekick.                  |  Pass  |
|   55 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   56 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   57 | Px has been changed with another player. | Px has been changed with another player. |  Pass  |
|   58 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   62 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   65 | Px has been changed with another player. | Px has been changed with another player. |  Pass  |
|   74 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   79 | Px has been changed with another player. | Px has been changed with another player. |  Pass  |
|   80 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|   81 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
|10000 |                                          |                                          |  Pass  |
```

Your Teacher, Tutor or Professor is not going to hand code each one of these test criteria, they are likely to use an app or script that they know to be correct, and run through a selection of numbers or all the possible numbers in the given range and compare the output.

If I run your code through all numbers from 0-91, you get 40 correct, and 51 wrong, fixing just the highlighted issues should be very simple. I hope you can see how constructing a matrix of test conditions and results can help you isolate the branches in the business requirements and how to test for obvious boundary or limit areas of failure.

> This is a special skill all by itself that you will need to evolve if you are going to become a good Software Engineer, I did this exercise in code because I'm an inherently lazy guy, but until you develop code techniques to do this, logic matrices are very easy to evaluate on paper, it helps you to identify the right inputs to use when self testing your code before you check it in for peer review. Many developers overlook the power or point of self testing for more conditions then the handful they came up with during development. Don't check in code that you are not 100% confident with and do not be 100% confident if you have not tested 100% of the possible combinations in your logic trees.